# Toolbar not showing, no errors

Tags: android

I am trying to make my app fit the new API's but I have a lot of trouble changing the old ActionBar to a Toolbar. It is just not showing up. Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener, FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:

            break;
        case R.id.settings:

            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the menu xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.adrissa.klea.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>



</menu>
```

This is the activity_main xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.adrissa.klea.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And finally the toolbar.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

I can see I'm not the only who is having trouble implementing the Toolbar instead of ActionBar, but I don't seem to find any of the proposed solutions, to fit my problems. I get no errors. Just no Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your style.xml , something like this :

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`parent = "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

also you can add your include inside a LinearLayout for example:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- up bar -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

also try this in toolbar.xml :

`android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot to add my styles.xml. have done now.

Comment: Maybe , you may put your toolbar outside the `NavigationDrawer` , both ( `NavigationDrawer` and toolbar ) inside a `LinearLayout`

Comment: I can't find any wrong i have the same implementation , please use my style.xml